# "Access violation" error when calling external function in DLL (unzip in unzipper.dll)

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to unzip a file using a `.dll` file that I got online however whenever I call the extract me procedure from the code section I receive the following error:

> Exception:
>   Access violation at address 025DA648. Read of address 00000000.

Procedure:

```pascal
procedure unzip(src, target: AnsiString);
external 'unzip@files:unzipper.dll cdecl delayload';

procedure ExtractMe(src, target : AnsiString);
begin
  unzip(ExpandConstant(src), ExpandConstant(target));
end;
```

Call from within `Code` section:

```pascal
procedure UnzipFiles();
var
  NSSMPath: string;
  target: AnsiString;
begin
  NSSMPath := ExpandConstant('{src}\..\nssm-2.24.zip');
  target := 'C:\files';
  begin
    //Unzips files Checks for presence of files before to save time.
    //NSSM
    if not (FileExists('C:\files\nssm-2.24'))then
    begin
      ExtractMe(NSSMPath, target)
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Get a working .dll?

Comment: It does work if I use Source: "{src}\..\nssm-2.24.zip"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: ExtractMe('C:\eltfiles\nssm-2.24.zip', 'C:\eltfiles') in the run section however I was trying to eliminate the extra .zip file in the DestDir.

Comment: Does the error indicate that the .dll is faulty? If so would you mind directing me to a web resource where I could learn more?

Comment: First, show us a real code. The code you have posted, won't even compile, as you have an undefined variable `target` in the `UnzipFiles`.

Comment: I edited the code.

Comment: OK, and now, if you call `ExtractMe('C:\eltfiles\nssm-2.24.zip', 'C:\eltfiles')` from the `UnzipFiles`, does it work or not?

Comment: Are you using Unicode and Ansi version of Inno Setup?

Comment: I switched to unicode and still get the error: " Exception: Access violation at address 037EA648 in module 'unzipper.dll'. Read of address 00000000.

Comment: And it still doesn't work if I make the ExtractMe edit you suggested in the files

Comment: So are you saying that `AfterInstall: ExtractMe('C:\eltfiles\nssm-2.24.zip', 'C:\eltfiles')` works, but the exactly the same call from the `UnzipFiles` fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `unzip` has to be declared as `stdcall`, not `cdecl`. Just use the declaration from the `UnzipExample.iss`:

```pascal
procedure unzip(src, target: AnsiString);
external 'unzip@files:unzipper.dll stdcall delayload';
```

Comment: This appears to work however oddly enough only if I specify the files to be unzipped in the [Files] section eg. Source: "{src}\..\apache-tomcat-7.0.69.zip"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: ExtractMe('C:\files\apache-tomcat-7.0.69.zip', 'C:\files'), I continue getting this error if I try to merely call the ExtractMe method in the code section.  But it works enough for me now, thanks.

Comment: You wrote that it work for you from the `AfterInstall` even before (what does not make sense by the way).